# How to prevent Snackbar from closing?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I'm using a control, called Snackbar, from a 3rd party library - github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary.

The problem is that **it is closing automatically**, like a Toast.

**What i am trying to do:** It should stay until i click `btn`

### Code snippet i am using

```
new SnackBar(ActSplash.this,
      "Do you want change color of this button to red?",
      "yes", 
       new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              ButtonFlat btn = (ButtonFlat) findViewById(R.id.buttonSnackBar);
             //btn.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
}).show();
```

### EDIT:

```
new SnackBar(ActSplash.this,
                                "Do you want change color of this button to red?",
                                "yes", new View.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                ButtonFlat btn = (ButtonFlat) findViewById(R.id.buttonSnackBar);
                                //btn.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            }
                        }).setIndeterminate(true)
                                .show();
```

***This shows a error cannot resolve show()***

---

### EDIT- FROM - NEW ANDROID DOCS

***How to prevent android snackbar from closing***

```
Snackbar
                 .make(((ActMedicalRecordDetailNew)getActivity()).getMainContent(), R.string.snackBarNoNetConnectivity, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction(R.string.snackBarTryAgain, new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
                            getActivity().finish();
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
```

Comment: is it part of the framework ?

Comment: Looks so..... Its cool ... I am using a backward compatibility library (https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary) check it ...  its like a crouton notification

Comment: no it is not. It is a third part library

Comment: @ Blackbelt .... I was looking at the google docs .... found this(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html) looks like its part of android library

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**Edit**:

`Snackbar` is now part of the new [Android Support Design library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html). you can use `LENGTH_INDEFINITE` as duration if you want to show it indefinitely. . You should drop the third party library you are using for it. Eg.

```
Snackbar.make(layout, R.string.snackBarNoNetConnectivity, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
    .show()
```

---

***Old answer***

you have to call `.setIndeterminate(true)` before calling `show()`

```
final SnackBar tmp = new SnackBar(ActSplash.this,
      "Do you want change color of this button to red?",
      "yes", 
       new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              ButtonFlat btn = (ButtonFlat) findViewById(R.id.buttonSnackBar);
             //btn.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
});
tmp.setIndeterminate(true);
tmp.show();
```

Comment: Third party library .... ? ... ok ...i was not aware of that. check thhe edit ... i cannot resolve this show()

Comment: `setIndeterminate` returns void not `SnackBar`. Assign the reference and call .setIndeterminate(true) before calling show()

Comment: @Devrath I ve update my answer. Let me know if you need help the android's version of snackbar. To show it indefinitely you can use `LENGTH_INDEFINITE` as duration

Comment: @Blackbelt , using either "-2" or `Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE` throws errors in Android Studio ...

Comment: @PhilipKahn you need the latest support design library to use `Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE`. (22.2.1)

Answer (score 15):

```
snackbar.setDuration(Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply do

```
Snackbar.make(layout, "Some text", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
    .show();
```