# What is this UI control and how can I make one in my app?

Tags: android, material-design

#### Background

In the following screenshot from Gmail, there is some sort of error bar shown just underneath the action bar / app bar. This bar shows permanently, and it pushes the remaining content down rather than overlaying it.

[image]

#### Questions

- Is there a name for this type of UI component/control?
- Is there something built-in or in the support libraries that I can use to add one of these to an activity of my own?

Comment: looks more like snackbar https://material.google.com/components/snackbars-toasts.html

Comment: Hmm..I'm not sure if it is a full blown widget, might just be a layout with a TextView.

Comment: @KaranMer, it does look similar, but as far as I know, snack bars are temporary and appear over the top of other things. This bar is permanent and pushes the content down.

Comment: @Sam: check this answer to know more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29921663/how-to-prevent-snackbar-from-closing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Material design has an example of this under [the App Errors section](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/errors.html#errors-app-errors). It refers to the control as:

> Container/component specific error with action

However, I also found an example in the Android Unified Email app, which refers to the control as *Tip View*:

- [ConversationTipView.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/UnifiedEmail/+/5f9b22e/src/com/android/mail/ui/ConversationTipView.java)
- [conversation_tip_view.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/UnifiedEmail/+/5f9b22e/res/layout/conversation_tip_view.xml)

I adapted the source code from the above to make my own:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tip_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#e5e5e5"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tip_view_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tip_view_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right|end"
        android:text="@string/preference_accessibility_service_enable"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"/>
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a Snackbar like @Karan says you can make it appear on the top like this:

```
Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(parentLayout, str, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
View view = snack.getView();
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params =(FrameLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
view.setLayoutParams(params);
snack.show();
```

This shows an animation of Snackbar sliding from bottom, then switching to top. If you want to avoid this try this library(I haven't tried this myself): https://github.com/AndreiD/TSnackBar

Comment: i suggest you to use a view and keep changing the visibilities when certain action is needed to be performed.

Answer (score -1):

Add a view inside of your current layout as per your design and make visibility gone, and make it visible when required from your activity/fragment.
when this will appear in the screen it pushes the remain content down from the current position.

For elevation you can use CARDVIEW.

hopefully it will help you;